# How to maintain wp_enqueue_style dependencies set in parent theme style enqueuing

Tags: child-theme, wp-enqueue-style

My parent theme's style.css has a dependency on bootstrap.css, which is also part of the parent theme.

From parent themes functions.php:

```
wp_enqueue_style('bootstrap', get_template_directory_uri().'/css/bootstrap.min.css);
wp_enqueue_style('style', get_stylesheet_uri(), array('bootstrap'));
```

When using a child theme the parents style.css gets loaded first, despite it having a dependency on bootstrap.

My child's style enqueuing function looks like this:

```
function child_enqueue_styles() {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'parent-style', get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css', 'parent-bootstrap');
}
```

And even when setting a dependency when enqueuing the parent style, it seems to be ignored and the style.css is loaded before bootstrap

```
function child_enqueue_styles() {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'parent-bootstrap', get_template_directory_uri().'/css/bootstrap.min.css');
    wp_enqueue_style( 'parent-style', get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css', 'parent-bootstrap');
}
```

I'm not sure how to deal with this without altering the parent theme

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm sure you missed it but the dependency parameter should be an array and not a string.

**So your enqueue function should be:**

```
function child_enqueue_styles() {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'parent-style', get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css', array('bootstrap'));
}
```

**or:**

```
function child_enqueue_styles() {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'parent-bootstrap', get_template_directory_uri().'/css/bootstrap.min.css');
    wp_enqueue_style( 'parent-style', get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css', array('parent-bootstrap'));
}
```

**Reference: [wp_enqueue_style](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_style/#parameters)**