# Font size decreases when child theme is created from parent theme?

Tags: css, child-theme, wp-enqueue-style

While creating and activating the child theme, the font size decreases as compared to parent theme

```
<?php function my_theme_enqueue_styles() {

$parent_style = 'spicepress-style'; // This is 'spicepress-style' for the Spicepress theme.

wp_enqueue_style( $parent_style, get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css' );
wp_enqueue_style( 'child-style',
    get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/style.css',
    array( $parent_style ),
    wp_get_theme()->get('Version')
);}add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_theme_enqueue_styles',10 );?>
```

Comment: Inspect the element's CSS with the browser's developer tools which each theme active. Do you notice any different rules being applied?

Comment: Hi Jacob, I searched and found that parent style has dependency on bootstrap.css. I added the dependency in functions.php and it worked out fine. Thanks for your effort and time !!

Answer (score 0):

Parent style had dependency on bootstrap.css. I added the dependency in the functions.php and it worked out fine.

Found this link helpful for my problem
https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/252360/153981